# DbSetT<T> vs IDbSet<T>

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, inversion-of-control, entity-framework-6

Recently, I've got request to make my DbContext model mockable.

However, currently it is defined like this:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}
```

I was thinking to abstract it to:

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    IDbSet<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}

public MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    IDbSet<Employee> Employees {get;set;}
}
```

Do I lose anything if I swap DbSet with IDbSet in my MyDbContext implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I think the mock and real database object should share the same interface.  That way you can swap out your database implementation without affecting clients.  Mocking is easier, too.  Aspect oriented programming is easier.  I can't think of a good reason *not* to start both with an interface.

Comment: DbSet has some methods that IDbSet does not expose. I'm interested in how much do I loose if I go with IDbSet in my DbContext class definition. This is more EF specific question rather than design pattern one.

Comment: Specifically for EF, you lose access to the `.AddRange()` functionality when you depend on the interface instead of the implementation.

The recommendation now is to depend on `DbSet<T>` instead of `IDbSet<T>`, and extend the `DbSet<T>` class when creating test doubles/mocks.